# Force Servicestack to delimit fields when producing CSV

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm using Servicestack to produce CSV. The data contains mobile (cell) phone numbers. These start with a leading zero e.g. 04053333888. My problem is the consumers open this file in Excel, which truncates the leading zero. They then report this as a bug.

How can I force Servicestack to delimit the values? Preferably only the fields containing phone numbers would have delimiters, but I'm OK forcing all values to be delimited. I know how to set a custom delimiter; I'm happy to use the default double quote ("). If I embed a double quote in the source data Servicestack escapes them and I end up with `"""04053333888"""` as the output. This is undesirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior isn't configurable, but you can just replace the escaped quotes with a single quote to remove the escaping, e.g:

```
var csv = records.ToCsv().Replace("\"\"\"","\"")
```